# How to print block from template?

Tags: blocks, theming

I have block template. How do I output this block on front page just by calling `render($page[region_name])`, where region_name is the name of a region to which the block is assigned.

**Edit:** I want to print the whole region assuming it contains only this block.

Comment: That's a little confusing, do you want to print the whole region or just one block from that region?

Comment: @Clive: I want to print the whole region assuming it contains only this block.

Comment: Ah, go with the answer from @dimitril below

Comment: do I have to create block through admin menu? If I do this then what I write to block body ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand...you would write whatever you want to appear in the block in the block body

Comment: why then use template file if we end up pasting its contents to block body?

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do now, I'll add an answer to see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off handling this in a custom module and declaring the block in there, then you don't need to worry about trying to inject the output from a template file into a custom block (using PHP in block bodies should be discouraged as it uses the evil `eval()` function).

The following is a generic example:

```
// Implements hook_theme()
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_block_template' => array(
      'template' => 'MYMODULE_block_template',
      'variables' => array()
    )
  );
}

// Implements hook_block_info()
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
  return array(
    'my_block' => array(
      'info' => t('My Block')
    )
  );
}

// Implements hook_block_view()
function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  if ($delta == 'my_block') {
    $block['subject'] = t('Block Title');
    $block['content'] = theme('MYMODULE_block_template');
  }

  return $block;
}
```

In the above code you declare a theme functino called `MYMODULE_block_template` which is attached to a template file in the root of your module folder (`MYMODULE_block_template.tpl.php`).

Once you install the module you'll have a block called 'My Block' in the blocks admin page that you will be able to assign to any region. The content of the block will be exactly what's contained in the `MYMODULE_block_template.tpl.php` file.

Comment: What you proposed has worked with the exception that this row "'template' => 'MYMODULE_block_template.tpl.php'," should be without '.tpl.php'

Comment: @OleksandrBondarenko You're right sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('region_name')); ?>
```

Comment: What if my blocks are added to the region through a Context? Your code doesn't seem to find any blocks in that case...